# Webhook subscription disabled. How to remove this error?

Tags: webhooks, messenger

[Screechshot of webhook being disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpj63.jpg)

Tried this command with my own access token:

curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps?access_token="

But this didn't work. What else should I try?

Answer (score 2):

Just make a new POST request with your page access token, like so:

```
curl -X POST "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/subscribed_apps?access_token=MY_SECRET_TOKEN"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try subscribing the page again under Products->Messenger->Settings->Webhook